# Merge two 99 byte TCP packets into one 198 byte TCP packet.

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I need to merge two TCP packets into one.  I wrote a socket emulator which reads a line of data from a csv file and outputs each line of data into two 99 byte binary packets every second.  I now need to write another emulator that will merge these two 99 byte packets into one 198 byte packet.

This is what I put together so far and it basically forwards both 99 byte packets from one emulator and relays it to the client as two 99 byte packets. I have tried a couple different things but cannot seem to figure out how to merge the two into one 198 byte packet.  Sounds simple, but i cannot wrap my head around it, suggestions will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

```
  package PacketFuser;

    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;

    public class PacketFuser {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        //Start server
        Socket socket = null;
        final ServerSocket ss  = new ServerSocket(6666);  
        System.out.println("Waiting on connection...");
        while (ss.isBound()){
            try {
                socket = ss.accept();
                System.out.println("Connected to port: " +socket.toString());
                }
                catch (IOException e){
                }

        //Start Client Socket
        InetAddress address=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        Socket c1=null;
        boolean client = false;

        while (client == false){
        try{
        System.out.println("waiting on Emulator");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        c1=new Socket(address, 31982);
        client = true;
        }
        catch (IOException e){} 
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        }
        System.out.println("Emulator Connected");


    //I need to figure out here how to catch two packets and merge them into one 198 byte packets here.

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(s1.getInputStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int pread;
        byte[] p1 = new byte[99];

        while ((pread = in.read(p1, 0, p1.length)) != -1 ) {
        buffer.write(p1, 0, pread);
        buffer.flush();
        socket.getOutputStream().write(p1);
        }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you are doing is pointless. TCP is streambased - there are no 99byte or 198byte packets on application level. You could get delievered the first 99bytes already with a 40 and 59byte read. And even if you try to write 198byte at once the other side might read those in completely different chunks.

Comment: I dont see how its pointless if there is a way to do it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `new byte[99]` for `new byte[198]`.

Comment: This helped! Thanks demogorii.. I just now need to sort the packets with the unique identifier inside to ensure they get streamed properly in the 198byte packet.